# opacity value being overwritten in IE Edge only

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have built [this HTML / CSS / jQuery game](http://mike-eng.com/sandbox/card2017/game.html), with the [code living here](https://github.com/mrengy/card2017). I'm having a bizarre bug with IE Edge.

What is supposed to happen is when the user clicks one of the elements that slide in from the sides of the screen, I am temporarily showing a "success" checkmark or an "error" "X" character, then fading them out using a CSS transition, which happens when I apply a class of "active" using jQuery.

The relevant HTML is:

```
<main id="targetcontainer">
  <div class="top target">
    <a href="#">&nbsp;</a>
  </div>
  <div id="feedback">
    <div id="success">&#x2714;</div>
    <div id="error">&#x274c;</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

and relevant CSS:

```
#targetcontainer{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 83%;
}

.top{
  width: 100%;
}

#feedback div{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left:0px;
  opacity: 0;
}

#feedback div.active{
  opacity:1;
  @include animation(200ms,800ms,ease-out,activeOut);
}
@include mykeyframe(activeOut){ from{opacity: 1;} to{opacity: 0;} }

.target a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

It's working as expected in Chrome. On IE Edge version 41.16299.15.0 , when I inspect the code and manually add the class of "active" to #success, I am still not seeing the checkmark, and inspecting the code in IE gives even stranger results:

Initially, I see that the "opacity: 1;" is being overwritten, though there is nothing above overwriting it.
[image: opacity:1 being overwritten]

Here's what this state should look like (shown correctly in Chrome):
[image: Chrome: success checkmark]

The computed tab points to lines 283 and 285 of card.scss:
[image: computed tab]

Here's the contents of those lines of code, which seems to have nothing to do with opacity:
[image: referenced lines of code]

I have mocked up [some of this in CodePen](https://codepen.io/mrengy/pen/YYpaBp) in case that's useful to start from, but I am not able to reproduce it there.

Comment: I tried your program and the behavior seemed to be consistent between IE, edge, and Chrome. What is the blue square above and exactly how does it relate to the problem. I never saw anything like that. The checks and Xs seemed to work the same. Any steps to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @Highdown click one of the items that animate in from the four sides of the window, and an "active" class will be applied to the "check mark" or the "x" symbol, making them visible. Or you can manually edit the html to add the class "active" to show one of those symbols. That behavior is not working in IE - they remain invisible in IE. Making them visible is only working in other browsers

Comment: I would focus on IE. I am pretty sure you have something going on outside of the code shown. Why? Play IE to the program end by intentionally selecting wrong answers. The program hangs and never ends. The Xs on bottom left are obviously the wrong color, but I think the program hang/not ending is a more tangible clue. Have you used try/catch that might be hiding an IE/Edge anomaly?

Comment: @Highdown thanks, but I'm not able to reproduce the issue of the program hanging on IE. I am not using any try/catch statements. When you say the Xs on the bottom left are the wrong color, I think what you mean is that the color specified in the css is green while the Xs are red. That is intentional and happens because the html character for the X itself actually makes it red.

Comment: On IE 11, the missed Xs are black, not red as they are in other browsers. At least on my laptop. Also, if I intentionally miss the answers, IE never goes to the end screen when all Xs are present bottom left. I downloaded the code and will have a look. I have it running and can step through some code. Also, IE does not have audio on my laptop.

Comment: The missed Xs that are black vs red are bottom left of screen, not the Big X that displays in the center of the screen. I am on Windows 10.

Comment: BTW, I am running the downloaded code, which may explain some differences between what you are seeing. The GitHub code may be outdated... Upload your latest and I download it.

Comment: Let me know if the CSS code I uploaded to SO worked. The compiled code on my machine is working on all major browsers. The checks/Xs fade out properly when an item is clicked.

Comment: @Highdown can you clarify for me what change you made in the CSS, perhaps by forking [the Github repository](https://github.com/mrengy/card2017) and making a commit. I'm having a hard time finding the change.

Comment: Look at my post in this question. I posted the complete CSS file in my answer. You can copy and do a diff to see the differences. It is mostly vendor stuff, but not all.

Answer (score 0):

Mike, I decided to submit an answer so that I can include an image to show you what I am experiencing on IE. The game should end (see all Xs bottom left), but instead it keeps presenting the four options to select. As I mentioned, no audio on IE, but do have audio on Edge, Chrome, and Firefox

I verified the downloaded code and this [site](http://mike-eng.com/sandbox/card2017/game.html) behave the same.

[image]

Stepping through the code on IE, there is a problem with the following code blocks.

```js
      //wait for success sound to finish
      soundSuccess.addEventListener("ended", function(){
        //when all characters in the message have been completed
        if ( messageLength == $('.completed').length ){
          //redirect to end screen once all letters have been clicked
          $(location).attr('href', 'end.html');
        }
      });

    } else {
      //show the error feedback since this item has been clicked already or is not in the messaage
      $('#error').addClass('active');
      soundError.play();
      //remove a life
      $('.life:not(.lost):last').addClass('lost');

      //wait for success sound to finish
      soundError.addEventListener("ended", function(){
        //when all lives have been lost
        if ( lives == $('.lost').length ){
          //redirect to game over screen once all letters have been clicked
          $(location).attr('href', 'gameover.html');
        }
      });
```

The two event listeners are never detecting a success or error. The code block within each event listener is never being executed.

I am using VS 2017 to debug this. I expect there may be some Audio incompatibility between IE and other browsers. There are some alternate ways of setting Audio up that IE might be happier with.

BTW, I played one game to the end. Nice picture of you, significant other, and cat...

---

**Update**

Apparently IE doesn't like the .wav file. I substituted .mp3 and that fixed the sound and the success/error event listeners work now. The game also ends properly for both success and failure. I did some additions to CSS for vendor specific stuff. If you want, I can send you the updated CSS (need email or upload point).

```
var soundSuccess = new Audio("sound/success.mp3");
var soundError = new Audio("sound/error.mp3");
```

The Xs bottom left are still black vs red for IE, which must be another issue.

---

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font: 100% "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1rem;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.fullscreen {
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

    .fullscreen div {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 9;
    }

    .fullscreen img {
        display: block;
    }

#end {
    color: #fff;
}

.staticscreen a {
    color: #fff;
}

.fullscreen h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-size: 7vw;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1rem black;
}

div.centered {
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    /* IE */
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.staticscreen {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

    .staticscreen div {
        text-align: left;
        width: auto;
    }

#end-message {
    top: 1em;
}

#buttons {
    right: 1rem;
    bottom: .5rem;
    z-index: 10;
}

    #buttons a {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        bottom: 0;
    }

#start-buttons {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 2em;
}

#targetcontainer {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 83%;
}

#instructions {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: .5rem;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.5rem;
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
}

    /* speech bubble pointer */
    #instructions:after {
        content: '';
        position: relative;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 15px 15px 0;
        border-color: #fff transparent;
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        margin-left: -15px;
        bottom: -1.3em;
        left: 20%;
    }

#kepler {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 1rem;
}

    #kepler img {
        width: 100px;
        width: 20vw;
    }

.button {
    background-color: #283;
    padding: .5rem;
    color: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.5rem;
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.button:hover {
        background-color: #4a5;
    }

.secondary {
    background-color: #666;
    margin-right: .5rem;
}

    .secondary:hover {
        background-color: #888;
    }

.fullscreen .button {
    font-size: .75rem;
}

.target, #feedback {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-font-variant-numeric: slashed-zero;
    font-variant-numeric: slashed-zero;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-size: 20vw;
}

#feedback {
    color: #283;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /* IE */
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/*
#feedback{
  color: $color-active;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
*/
    #feedback div {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        /* IE */
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        /* Firefox */
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        /* Safari and Chrome */
        -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        opacity: 0;
    }

/* show and quickly fade out the feedback on success or error */
        #feedback div.active {
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 200ms;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 400ms;
            -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            -webkit-animation-name: activeOut;
            -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
            -moz-animation-delay: 200ms;
            -moz-animation-duration: 400ms;
            -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            -moz-animation-name: activeOut;
            -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
            -o-animation-delay: 200ms;
            -o-animation-duration: 400ms;
            -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            -o-animation-name: activeOut;
            -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
            animation-delay: 200ms;
            animation-duration: 400ms;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-name: activeOut;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
        }

@-webkit-keyframes activeOut {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes activeOut {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes activeOut {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes activeOut {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
/* max font size */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .target, #feedback {
        font-size: 154px;
    }
}

.target a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    /*user-drag: none;*/
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.top img, .bottom img {
    max-width: 25%;
}

.top img, .top span {
    vertical-align: top;
}

/* nudge text up to be in the same place as an image, despite room on top of the letter in the font */
.top span {
    display: block;
}

.left img, .right img {
    max-width: 50%;
}

.top {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-name: inTop;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    -moz-animation-delay: 0;
    -moz-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-animation-name: inTop;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    -o-animation-delay: 0;
    -o-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-animation-name: inTop;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    animation-delay: 0;
    animation-duration: 800ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-name: inTop;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
}

@-webkit-keyframes inTop {
    from {
        margin-top: -50%;
    }

    to {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes inTop {
    from {
        margin-top: -50%;
    }

    to {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes inTop {
    from {
        margin-top: -50%;
    }

    to {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes inTop {
    from {
        margin-top: -50%;
    }

    to {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}

.top.out {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-name: outTop;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    -moz-animation-delay: 0;
    -moz-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-animation-name: outTop;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    -o-animation-delay: 0;
    -o-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -o-animation-name: outTop;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    animation-delay: 0;
    animation-duration: 800ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-name: outTop;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
}

@-webkit-keyframes outTop {
    from {
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    to {
        margin-top: -50%;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes outTop {
    from {
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    to {
        margin-top: -50%;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes outTop {
    from {
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    to {
        margin-top: -50%;
    }
}

@keyframes outTop {
    from {
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    to {
        margin-top: -50%;
    }
}

.right {
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    /* IE */
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-name: inRight;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    -moz-animation-delay: 0;
    -moz-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-animation-name: inRight;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    -o-animation-delay: 0;
    -o-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-animation-name: inRight;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    animation-delay: 0;
    animation-duration: 800ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-name: inRight;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
}

@-webkit-keyframes inRight {
    from {
        margin-right: -50%;
    }

    to {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes inRight {
    from {
        margin-right: -50%;
    }

    to {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes inRight {
    from {
        margin-right: -50%;
    }

    to {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes inRight {
    from {
        margin-right: -50%;
    }

    to {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}

.right.out {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-name: outRight;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    -moz-animation-delay: 0;
    -moz-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-animation-name: outRight;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    -o-animation-delay: 0;
    -o-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -o-animation-name: outRight;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    animation-delay: 0;
    animation-duration: 800ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-name: outRight;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
}

@-webkit-keyframes outRight {
    from {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    to {
        margin-right: -50%;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes outRight {
    from {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    to {
        margin-right: -50%;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes outRight {
    from {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    to {
        margin-right: -50%;
    }
}

@keyframes outRight {
    from {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    to {
        margin-right: -50%;
    }
}

.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-name: inBottom;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    -moz-animation-delay: 0;
    -moz-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-animation-name: inBottom;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    -o-animation-delay: 0;
    -o-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-animation-name: inBottom;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    animation-delay: 0;
    animation-duration: 800ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-name: inBottom;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
}

@-webkit-keyframes inBottom {
    from {
        margin-bottom: -50%;
    }

    to {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes inBottom {
    from {
        margin-bottom: -50%;
    }

    to {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes inBottom {
    from {
        margin-bottom: -50%;
    }

    to {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes inBottom {
    from {
        margin-bottom: -50%;
    }

    to {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}

.bottom.out {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-name: outBottom;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    -moz-animation-delay: 0;
    -moz-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-animation-name: outBottom;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    -o-animation-delay: 0;
    -o-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -o-animation-name: outBottom;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    animation-delay: 0;
    animation-duration: 800ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-name: outBottom;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
}

@-webkit-keyframes outBottom {
    from {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    to {
        margin-bottom: -50%;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes outBottom {
    from {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    to {
        margin-bottom: -50%;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes outBottom {
    from {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    to {
        margin-bottom: -50%;
    }
}

@keyframes outBottom {
    from {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    to {
        margin-bottom: -50%;
    }
}

.bottom img, .bottom span {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.left {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    /* IE */
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-name: inLeft;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    -moz-animation-delay: 0;
    -moz-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-animation-name: inLeft;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    -o-animation-delay: 0;
    -o-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-animation-name: inLeft;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    animation-delay: 0;
    animation-duration: 800ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-name: inLeft;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
}

@-webkit-keyframes inLeft {
    from {
        margin-left: -50%;
    }

    to {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes inLeft {
    from {
        margin-left: -50%;
    }

    to {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes inLeft {
    from {
        margin-left: -50%;
    }

    to {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes inLeft {
    from {
        margin-left: -50%;
    }

    to {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}

.left.out {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-name: outLeft;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    -moz-animation-delay: 0;
    -moz-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-animation-name: outLeft;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    -o-animation-delay: 0;
    -o-animation-duration: 800ms;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -o-animation-name: outLeft;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    animation-delay: 0;
    animation-duration: 800ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-name: outLeft;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
}

@-webkit-keyframes outLeft {
    from {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    to {
        margin-left: -50%;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes outLeft {
    from {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    to {
        margin-left: -50%;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes outLeft {
    from {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    to {
        margin-left: -50%;
    }
}

@keyframes outLeft {
    from {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    to {
        margin-left: -50%;
    }
}

#hud {
    margin-top: 1em;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: left;
}

#lives {
    margin-top: .2em;
}

.life {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

    .life img {
        width: 1em;
    }

.lost img {
    opacity: .5;
}

.lost::after {
    content: "\00274C";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.item {
    margin-right: .1em;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px #333 solid;
}

    .item.space {
        border-bottom: none;
    }

.item-letter {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.completed .item-letter {
    visibility: visible;
}

.item img {
    max-width: 2em;
    max-height: 2em;
}

.lightning {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 216px;
    height: 120px;
    top: 0;
    /*user-drag: none;*/
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.lightningLeft {
    left: -216px;
}

.lightningRight {
    right: -216px;
    -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    transform: scale(-1, 1);
    display: none;
}

.upsidedown {
    -moz-transform: scale(1, -1);
    -o-transform: scale(1, -1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, -1);
    transform: scale(1, -1);
}

.em {
    font-style: italic;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=card.css.map */
```

This is a screen shot for Edge.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I converted the audio files to mp3 as you suggested, so perhaps that fixed the different issue you mentioned. I'm still not able to resolve or figure out what is causing (in IE Edge) the checkmark or "X" in the center of the screen to not be visible after clicking one of the characters that animates in from the side though (the original question). I added a screenshot of the desired state (shown correctly in Chrome) to clarify.

Comment: Mike, Edge works perfectly including the green check. As I mentioned, I modified the CSS to account for vendor properties. That may account for the differences. I just added the CSS file that I updated.